# Tabu search examples

Tags: artificial-intelligence, tabu-search

Do you know a good  and most important detailed Tabu search example.

Something not to hard, as I am in the way to understand this cool algorithm.

I have found this [tutorial](http://www.cse.unt.edu/~garlick/teaching/4310/assign/TS%20-%20Tutorial.pdf) and this with a [SAT problem](http://webmining.spd.louisville.edu/Websites/COMB-OPT/LECTURES/Lecture-Tabu-Search.pdf), but it is not  very detailed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned it from Wikipedia years ago, but **[this book](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/) is much better**. For code examples, take a look at [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/)'s [source code](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [blog](http://voidexception.weebly.com/simple-tabu-search-using-java---traveling-sales-man-tsp.html) about tabu search and how it's used to solve the TSP, 
along with the java implementation. I hope it's of help.

Answer (score 1):

[Clever Algorithms](http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/) by Jason Brownlee PhD describes [Tabu Search](http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/stochastic/tabu_search.html) and also includes sample Ruby code.